# Disable Serialization for Specific Property

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a class object for XML serialization

```
[XmlType("PAYMENT")]
public class PaymentXML
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "REQUEST")]
    public RequestXML Request { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "META")]
    public MetaXML Request { get; set; }

    //Property that I dont want to be serialized
    public Subscriber Subscriber { get; set; }
}
```

the serialization

```
var xml = new PaymentXML();

string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@_xmlResponseDir + _responsePath);

using (var sw = new StreamWriter(path))
{
    var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PaymentXML), new XmlRootAttribute("XML"));

    serializer.Serialize(sw, xml, ns);
}
```

The problem is, it's also serializing the `Subscriber` property. I only want the `RequestXML` and `MetaXML` to be serialized into XML. **How can I exclude the `Subscriber` property in the serialization process?**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the [[XmlIgnore]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
// Property that I don't want to be serialized.
[XmlIgnore]
public Subscriber Subscriber { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 9):

Add the [XmlIgnore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx) attribute to that property.